# How to navigate to different class views in django based on user type?

Tags: python, django

Suppose the url is like this: `www.example.com/<username>` and the user has two types: regular and premium. I wanna use two different views to generate these two different user home pages. How should I write the corresponding `urls.py` and `views.py` files to achieve this. By the way, the two different views have been set up and both are class-based view, I just don't know how to do this switch based on user type.

Comment: Do you store the type of user in a database? If yes then I'd say it's just  matter of a simple `if` statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a middle view which "dispatches" the correct view. That way, you can still have one url. So just point that one url to this view:

```
class HomePageDispatchView(View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.type == PREMIUM:
            return PremiumHomePage.as_view()(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return RegularHomePage.as_view()(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This is actually very similar to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19119131/2761986. I use this pattern quite frequently. It allows for keeping code separate, but using the same url.

Comment: `__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)` I got this error msg:(

Comment: What does your url definition look like?

Comment: Sorry, I made another mistake. It's ok now. Thanks a lot!